# $RL$ Circuit current derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, inductance

I am having trouble with the following question:

> "After the current in the circuit of Fig. P30.63 has reached its final, steady value with switch $S_1$ closed and $S_2$ opened, switch $S_2$ is closed, thus short-circuiting the inductor. (Switch $S_1$ remains closed. See Problem 30.63 for numerical values of the circuit elements.) Derive expressions for the currents through $R_0$, $R$, and $S_2$ as functions of the time $t$ has elapsed since $S_2$ was closed."

Here is the figure given in the question:
[image]

I understood that the current through $R_0$ remains constant, but I am having trouble deriving the expression for the current through $R$. The answer seems to be $$i_R(t)=\frac{\mathcal{E}}{R_\text{eq}}e^{-(R/L)t} \quad,$$ but I don't see how to obtain this expression. Can someone please show me the derivation of this with steps and explanations?

Answer (score 1):

In the small loop, after $S_2$ is closed: iR = - L(di/dt).  (Negative because, i, is decreasing with time.) Experience shows that this type of equation has a solution of the form: i =A$e^{αt}$.  Find (di/dt) and solve the equation for α.  The constant, A, will be the initial current.

Comment: Agree with R.W., also, notice that the short between `c` and `b` by S2 effectively takes those elements right out of the rest of the circuit.  That will help you find current through `R0` easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework-like question, I will only give
the steps, but leave out the calculational details.

Choose your time scale such that the switch $S_2$ closes when $t=0$.
Consider first the situation when switch $S_2$ is still open,
i.e. for $t_0\le 0$.

- Because switch $S_2$ is open, $R_0$, $R$ and $L$ are in series
  and the currents through these are all the same.
- Because the system is in steady state, the current through
  $R_0$, $R$ and $L$ doesn't change with time, and hence
  the voltage across $L$ is zero.
- Because the resistors $R_0$ and $R$ are in series,
  you should know how to calculate their equivalent resistance
  $R_\text{eq}$ from $R_0$ and $R$.
- From Ohm's law you can calculate the current by
  $$i_R=\frac{\mathcal{E}}{R_\text{eq}} \tag{1}$$

And now consider the situation after $S_2$ closes, i.e. for $t\ge 0$:

- From Ohm's law the voltage accross resistor $R$ is $U_R(t)=Ri_R(t)$.
- From the definition of inductance the voltage across
  inductor $L$ is $U_L(t)=L\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}$.
- Because $R$ and $L$ are in series, the currents through these are
  the same: $i_R(t)=i_L(t)$.
- Because switch $S_2$ is closed the voltage between $c$ and $b$ is zero:
  $U_R(t)+U_L(t)=0$.
- Putting together the previous  4 facts, you will get a differential
  equation for $i_R(t)$.
- From (1) you have the starting condition for $i_R(0)$.
- Now find the solution $i_R(t)$ of the differential equation
  with the starting condition.